# Padronização de Controller Web API

Tags: url, controller, asp.net-web-api, uri

Gostaria de saber o seguinte.

Imaginem as seguintes URI:

(1) api/pedidos
(2) api/pedidos/10
(3) api/pedidos/10/itens

A URI (1) e (2) estou certo de que estariam dentro de um classe chamada PedidosController, já a (3), estou com dúvida se seria na mesma ou em outra classe chamada ItensController.

Qual o correto?

Answer (score 0):

Como esta trabalhando micro serviço acredito que melhor maneira seja deixar separado mesmo

PedidoController

api/pedidos

api/pedidos/10

ItemController

api/item // todos itens
api/item/{id} // item com determinado id

artigo falando sobre assunto :
https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/dn376303.aspx

Comment: Eduardo, boa tarde e obrigado pelo retorno.

Então, mas se você olhar o artigo que você citou, ele faz diferente do que você recomendou, pois:

O método de recuperar os álbuns dos artistas está no ArtistasController e não no AlbunsController.

E entendo que isso é a mesma lógica do meu exemplo, assim como pedidos tem itens, artistas tem álbuns.